# No Panels for Other user in xubuntu

Tags: login, xubuntu, users, xfce-panel

My xsession when logged in with other user than myself doesnot show the default two panels. All I get is the desktop with wallpaper. Anyone got any idea what is wrong ? I am using xubuntu 10.04. It doesnot happen while I setup a user and login with his/her name but after some times of logins.

Comment: Can you check if there are any error messages in the `~/.xsession-errors` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panels disappear often in Xfce. The developers are still trying to resolve the issue. This seems to be a particularly difficult issue for them. You can try installing the panels when they are missing. A good guide for doing that exists at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XubuntuPanels .